# function/module to achive a replacement as follows

Tags: functions, replacement

I want to shorten some long expressions by using some new parameters. So, I want to
create a function/module to achive a (multiple) replacement as follows:

```
    Unevaluated[-((
       Sqrt[3] E^(k x - \[Xi] - (
          t (2 k Subscript[a, 1] Subscript[b, 2] + 
             Subscript[b, 
              1] (1 - k Subscript[a, 2] + 2 k^2 Subscript[b, 2])))/(
          \[Beta] Subscript[b, 
           2] (Subscript[a, 2] + 2 k Subscript[b, 2]))) Sqrt[Subscript[b, 
        1]] Tan[x])/Sqrt[
       k  (-2 k + (k^2 + 2 \[Gamma]^2) Subscript[a, 2]) Subscript[b, 
        2]])] 
/.
 { 
      HoldPattern[Sqrt[
        k  (-2 k + (k^2 + 2 \[Gamma]^2) Subscript[a, 2]) Subscript[b, 
         2]]] 
:> A, 
      HoldPattern@((
        t (2 k Subscript[a, 1] Subscript[b, 2] + 
           Subscript[b, 
            1] (1 - k Subscript[a, 2] + 2 k^2 Subscript[b, 2])))/(
        \[Beta] Subscript[b, 
         2] (Subscript[a, 2] + 2 k Subscript[b, 2]))) -> B
}
```

TRY: (limitness:it doesn' t work every time and  it is for a just one replacement)

```
  Substitute[expr_, oldvars_, newvars_] := 
 Unevaluated[expr] /. HoldPattern[oldvars] :> newvars
```

Comment: Dear @RF_1, respectfully, if you worked a little bit on making your question simple and concise, for example provide simple expressions rather than your complicated expression which contains a lot of noise, then it would be easier to answer, and more importantly, it would potentially be useful for other people. In this form, any answer will not be useful for anyone except you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not exactly know what you want, but perhaps you are missing a `HoldAll`?

```
SetAttributes[Substitute,HoldAll];
Substitute[expr_,oldvars_,newvars_]:=Unevaluated[expr]/. HoldPattern[oldvars]:>newvars;
```

For example, assuming `a` and `b` have no definitions associated to them,

```
Substitute[a+1/(b+b),b+b,2]
```

will return

```
1/2+a
```

Without the `HoldAll` attribute, it returns

```
a+1/(2*b)
```

**Edit:** If in addition to the above one defines

```
Substitute[expr_,oldvars_,newvars_,others__]:=Substitute[Substitute[expr,oldvars,newvars],others];
```

then multiple replacement rules can be given, for example

```
Substitute[(a-a)/(b-b)+c,a-a,2,b-b,7,c,d]
```

will give

```
2/7+d
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Thank you. All right, how to multiple replacement in once?

Comment: In your short example, you replaced b+b with 2. Besides, how to replace a with c in once by defining apropriate command `Substitute`.

Comment: Does the edit do what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is the result which I want. All right, what do you think more elagant form of inputs such as  `Substitute[(a - a)/(b - b) + c, {a - a -> 2, b - b -> 7, c -> d}]`